SvelteKit is wrapping my response and I can't figure out why
I have a SvelteKit action that looks like this:
export const actions = {
    upload: async ({request}) => {
        // some logic

        return { success: true };
    }
}

However, when I call this endpoint the response returned looks like this according to my browser's network tab:
{"type":"success","status":200,"data":"[{\"success\":1},true]"}
I tried:

default action vs named action
no middlewares set up


A form action's result will always follow that pattern (and has to or you'll run into an error). See here https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-actionresult  What are you wanting it to do instead? You can return any data you want back, but it'll still append the type and status keys for you. In your example sending success back is redundant.

@gaffney is there any way to prevent it? I am using editor.js/image and it expects a certain JSON when the upload is successful on the FE

You could perhaps fetch() a self-created API endpoint instead instead of it being a form submission? Like onclick, run a fetch function, check the json response. https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/get-handlers

I've never used a SvelteKit app as a JSON API, so I might be wrong, but if you use the json() function, the response body might contain only your data.
